# Export certain things from a sql database?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

i have a 23gb .sql file (MySQL Database) and id like to export certain tables.
So far in my previous database's i have had to import the whole thing into my local Mysql database but it has been really time consuming. I have been using XAMPP and manually importing the whole .sql file which takes 8-12 hours for such large files.
Is there anything that can help me speed up this whole proccess?

Thanks

Comment: If the export was done using mysqldump then the sql file is just a text file which you can parse and extract only the tables you want. See for example how to extract the tables from the dump, [here](https://tecadmin.net/extract-tables-backup-from-full-mysql-dump/)

Comment: You should try by dumping sql via command `mysqldump --add-drop-table -u admin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` dbname > dbname.sql` something like this

Comment: Does the database still exist in MySQL? Exporting only the tables you want (or at least breaking it up per-table) would give you a lot more flexibility than one gigantic file. Failing that, I like Sergiu's suggestion to split the existing file with a tool to process the file before importing to MySQL. Finally, when doing your actual import, I'd definitely use the command line import process rather than going through any tool like phpMyAdmin that would slow down processing such a huge file.